# How to manage multiple alfresco repositories?

Tags: alfresco

**Problem description:**

I have multiple alfresco installations (development, testing, production) of one project.
I need to copy files under *Data Dictionary* folder (Scripts, Templates, Web Scripts) from one to another in one direction (development -> testing  -> production).

**Current solution:**

I copy files manually via webdav, which is annoying and unreliable (I can forget to copy some.).

**Desired solution:**

I'd like to have I tool, which will copy changed files at my command, what they are ready for the next step. I had an idea, that it could internally use a Git repository with branches for each installation, being able to fetch the files from *devel* and push the files to *testing* and *production*. This way (with Git) it could also support reverting changes.

It looks like a quite common problem, but I wasn't able to google something about it, so I'm asking here. Does such a tool exist or is there a better way of managing multiple repositories?

Comment: Did you look at using the TransferService or ReplicationService?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a brand new installation of your development/testing/production Alfresco instances, you could simply migrate alf_data dir content, that contains by default db, indexes, content-store, backup files. If you need, you could migrate the "shared" folder too, or at least some files from the shared folder as could be some Alfresco customization (custom scripts or similar). Here is the link that helps with migration steps:
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/System_Migration

Otherwise, if you need only to move a folder from Data Dictionary, or a set of documents, you could use ACP in order to achieve that. Here is the wiki for doing this: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Export_and_Import

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via **FTP**. When your want to deploy new changes, you can go with manual client like FileZila to download changes from Dev, then upload them to test.

But you can also automate FTP, so that it can run a scheduled check if there are new things on, say, dev and push them to test.

If you use Git for source control, you could also do this via **[git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp)**. Hold a copy of Data Dictionary in your source folder, then add some sort of pre-commit check, which will see if you changed any of those files. If you did, on commit it will push the change to dev and test.

Answer (score 0):

I think Relication service AF is suitable for you.

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Community_3.4.a#Replication